# How Change name file after Creation in startup folder?

Tags: c#, startup

I With Code my application added to startup
how I can after Creation File (filename + ".url") Change To (filename + ".exe")

```
static string filename = "troj";
    public static string tempure = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\" + filename + ".exe";
   public static string tempurepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\";
     public static void addtostart()
    {
        try
        {
            string deskDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(deskDir + "\\" + filename + ".url")) return;
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(deskDir + "\\" + filename + ".url"))
            {
                string app = tempure;
                writer.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
                writer.WriteLine("URL=file:///" + app);
                writer.WriteLine("IconIndex=0");
                string icon = app.Replace('\\', '/');
                writer.WriteLine("IconFile=" + icon);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
```

Comment: Explain it little bit more, your question is unclear to me.

Comment: why don't you just create it with ".exe" ?

Comment: I with StreamWriter(deskDir + "\\" + filename + ".url") Make file in startup I want after make file 5 second Later file Change name To filename + ".exe"